# Is there a limit on the number of concurrent requests in DropWizard

Tags: configuration, dropwizard

Is there any limit on the maximum number of concurrent requests that Dropwizard can handle?

Does Jersey have the same limit?

Answer (score 5):

There is `maxQueuedRequests` property which limits the maximum number of requests to queue before blocking the acceptor threads. The default value is *1024*.
You should check the [configuration reference](http://www.dropwizard.io/0.9.2/docs/manual/configuration.html#all).